# How does akka stream throttle work?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

```
def throttle(elements: Int, per: FiniteDuration, maximumBurst: Int, mode: ThrottleMode): Repr[Out]
```

Does `maximumBurst` means the number of elements that can be processed at the same time ?

Answer (score 7):

From the [scaladoc](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/Flow.html#throttle(elements:Int,per:scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration,maximumBurst:Int,mode:akka.stream.ThrottleMode):FlowOps.this.Repr[Out]):

> Throttle implements the token bucket model. There is a bucket with a
>   given token capacity (burst size or maximumBurst). Tokens drops into
>   the bucket at a given rate and can be 'spared' for later use up to
>   bucket capacity to allow some burstiness. Whenever stream wants to
>   send an element, it takes as many tokens from the bucket as number of
>   elements. If there isn't any, throttle waits until the bucket
>   accumulates enough tokens. Bucket is full when stream just
>   materialized and started.

`maximumBurst` is the token bucket size in the model described above.
Say we start a throttled stream, and the sink starts demanding elements. The throttle stage will emit `maximumBurst` of them before backpressuring (with shaping mode) or failing (with enforcing mode).

So I would say it is the maximum number of elements that can be processed without throttling. Processed "at the same time" is never going to be an exact definition in a stream :)